# Convert pythonic loop into traditional loop style

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python and kindly I have a question: Given the following:

```
np.asarray([self.simulate(c) for c in challenges])
```

I want to break it down to look familiar in the traditional coding way. Can I say it is equivalent to:

```
for c in challenges:
    y = self.simulate(c)
    y = np.asarray[y]
```

Thank you.

Comment: no, you're losing the cumulative effect, and `y` is overwritten at each iteration. create a list and append to it. Then build your array.

Comment: you will want to predeclare y as a list before the loop and do y.append(self.simulate....) and after the loop for np.asarray(y)

Answer (score 4):

It's not called "pythonic looping", but [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

The equivalent would be:

```
items = []
for c in challenges:
    items.append(self.simulate(c))

nparr = np.asarray(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your method is that **you're are not building a list**, such as this list comprehension does. Rather, you are simply indexing one item from `np.asarray`, and never saving the value. Furthermore, you don't even want to be indexing `np.asarray`, you want to pass a list to its constructor.

You need to create a temporary list to hold the return value of `self.simulate(c)` on each iteration of `challenges` and pass *that* list to `np.asarray`:

```
temp = []
for c in challenges:
    temp.append(self.simulate(c))
array = np.asarray(temp)
```

Also, just to let you know, the "pythonic loop" you're referring to is usually called a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). "Pythonic" is just a name us Python community members use to describe something that is idiomatic to the Python language and its ideals.